# I cannot brawl properly against Chief Mauhulakh

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I went to an Orc Stronghold. I met this guy: https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Chief_Mauhulakh.

He asked for a brawl. While we were brawling, Serana casted something on him. He was running away, putting his hand on his head. I thought a few more punches and it would work. My character then did the judo throw kill animation on him to the snow. He's dead.

I tried to resurrect him with console commands. If I click, I see a number: 00000014. I am not sure if it's the ref id or base id for resurrect. In the wiki page, I see 0001b098. Neither works.

Here is the screenshot:

[image: screenshot of entered console commands]

I didn't expect the brawl to turn into a deadly battle.

My last save is quite far back but I loaded it anyway. I dismissed my follower, removed all equipment, and asked the guy for brawling again. It seems that again and again, the brawl will turn into a normal fight.

Either the guy brings axes or runs away or whatever. Depleting his HP means killing him. Casting pacify means I cannot get my 100 septims back.

Comment: You live with it.

Comment: Are you able to brawl normally with other NPC's?

Comment: I really wonder why your first instinct is to monkey with the console, which can cause all sorts of additional problems, rather than loading a previous save.

Comment: I did use the previous save. Still, the guy died. Of course, my save is close now. Then I tried the mod in the accepted answer. It works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You used incorrect console commands to resurrect Chief Mauhulakh as per that console error message: "Unknown variable x for parameter Integer (Optional)." It's not `resurrect [RefID]`. The correct console commands are: `prid [RefID]` and then `resurrect 1`. See [How do I resurrect companions / followers?](/a/86339/4797) for more info.

To avoid bugs and other unwanted issues with brawling, install the [**Modern Brawl Bug Fix** (original / Legendary Edition)](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/77465) / [(Special Edition)](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/1473) mod:

> Brawls are poorly implemented in Skyrim. Any magic effects applied to either participant will cancel the brawl and may cause the opponent to pull out their weapon. Depending on your load order, you may experience the infamous "**Brawl Bug**" that prevents you from completing any brawls.
>
> The Modern Brawl Bug Fix updates [brawl-related] scripts.
> In the vanilla game, brawls (and certain other controlled combat
> scenarios) are cancelled when either participant is struck by a magic
> effect. This mod updates these events to trigger only when a
> participant is struck by a weapon (except fists), *hostile* spell, shout
> or scroll or when the player casts a spell, uses an ingredient or uses
> a potion during the brawl.

Comment: I did that before you answer and it works perfectly. I have no idea what magical effect affect any party without the mod. I think something triggers the hostility.

Comment: @user4951 It is possible that another mod is adding a magical effect to one of the participants in the brawl. Also, wearing the Ebony Mail armor will cause brawl bugs too.

Comment: A `recycleactor` command may be necessary in some cases if the AI packages are not resetting e.g. shopkeepers not opening their shops after resurrection. This will work even if the body has been cleaned up.